# nested div not filling the width of the parent div

Tags: html, css

Maybe because it is late and I am super tired, but I am having an issue trying to get a nested div to stay at the bottom of the parent div and also be the full width inside the parent div padding.

The site is here: http://www.ecoscapecabins.com/wp-2016/ I am referring to the section with the cabins. div class= es-cabin-pricing it will not fill the parent div like the content above does.

```
    <div class="mkd-ptfs-item">
            <div class="mkd-ptfs-item-image">
        <a href="http://www.ecoscapecabins.com/wp-2016/portfolio-item/cabin-1-features/">
                                <img src="http://www.ecoscapecabins.com/wp-2016/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/cabin-1-362x263.jpg" alt="" width="362" height="263">                            </a>
    </div>
    <div class="mkd-ptfs-item-content">
        <h4 class="mkd-ptfs-item-title">
        <a href="http://www.ecoscapecabins.com/wp-2016/portfolio-item/cabin-1-features/">CABIN 1 FEATURES</a>
    </h4>
    <div class="mkd-ptfs-item-excerpt-holder">
        <p></p><p>Large Cedar Wrap-around Deck  •  Fully Equipped Kitchenette  •  Private River Rock Shower  •  Flat Screen Satellite TV •  Private Fire Pit  •  Queen Bed</p>
    <div class="es-cabin-pricing">
    <div class="es-cabin-left">May – Sep<br>
    <span class="es-price">$180/night</span></div>
    <div class="es-cabin-right">Oct – Apr<br>
    <span class="es-price">$130/night</span></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

CSS =

```
    .es-cabin-pricing {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
display: block;
float: none;
width: initial;


    .es-cabin-left {
width: 45%;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 20px;
float: left;
display: block;


    .es-cabin-right {
width: 45%;
margin-left: 10px;
position: relative;
margin-bottom: 20px;
float: right;
display: block;
```

[image]

This is how I want it to look at the bottom with the dates/prices (I cannot force a specified width though because they scale, that is why I need the es-cabin-pricing div to just fill the width of the parent div:

[image]
Thanks for the help.

Comment: instead of posting link please add your relevant codes

Comment: Yes, it seems you are too tired. You forgot to add your code instead of link and image.

Comment: sorry code is there now

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Can you maybe add a result-picture ?

Comment: added the result picture and desired outcome. Thanks DomeTune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.mkd-ptfs-item-content {
    padding: 0 25px 20px;
    min-height: 230px;
    position: relative;
}

.es-cabin-pricing {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 25px;
    right: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add below styles to fix it....

```
.es-cabin-pricing {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

.mkd-ptfs-item-content {
    position: relative;
}
```

if you use position absolute , it will not use width 100% unless given and position relative is given to make  class `es-cabin-pricing` take position and width related to class `mkd-ptfs-item-content`

Comment: setting width to 100% didn't work, I tried that before and it was going outside the parent div, the previous answer above worked though